# VBA excel - loop in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, i'd like to point out im a beginner in VBA excel coding.
I can't seem to know how to code a loop in a loop for the following problem:
My excel has in column D the following info:
D2:12, 
D3:12,
D4:5

and im trying to automate column E as following:
E1 to E12 would be the information in D2,
E13 to E25 would be the information in D3. etc... up to a certain established threshold.

I currently have coded the following:

```
Sub salairemensuelle()

Dim xrow As Integer, xcol As interger, n As Integer, nbrdecolonnedemois As Integer 

xrow = 2 

xcol = 4

Do Until Cells(xrow, xcol).Value >= 25 'threshold of 25
        n = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row 'finding row of D column
        For nbrdecolonnedemois = 1 To n

End Sub
```

I seem to be stuck here since i dont know how to loop the first D column and then closing both loops.

Could anybody take a look. Thanks

Comment: +1 for an Excel question that belongs on StackOverflow :) but I don't think this code can compile...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need two loops for this.  Neither of your loops are closed, though.

You close a `Do` with `Loop`, (or `Loop While`, etc.) e.g,:

```
Do Until i >= 10

    i = i+1

Loop
```

You create a `For` loop with the `Next` statement, e.g., :

```
For i = 1 to 10
    MsgBox i
Next
```

In your case, I think you can just use a `For ... Next` loop with an `Exit For` statement when the threshold condition obtains:

```
Sub salairemensuelle()

Dim xrow As Integer, xcol As interger, n As Integer, nbrdecolonnedemois As Integer 

xrow = 2 
xcol = 4

        n = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row 'finding row of D column
        For nbrdecolonnedemois = 1 To n
            'The next line terminates the loop if threshold of 25 is met:
            If Cells(xrow, xcol).Value >= 25 Then 
                Exit For
            Else:
                '### The rest of your code operates inside this ELSE block
            End If

        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The following line: if cells(xrow,xcol).value >=25 then, would only check if any row in column D goes over the threshold. How would you rewrite it as to take into account the cumulative amounts of column D. AKA for a threshold of 25, the last information taking into acount would be D4 since 12 + 12+1 would be 25.

Comment: *would only check if any row in column D goes over the threshold.*  No: This checks **only** Cell `D2`.  I assume that this cell contains some sort of sum formula, and its value will change as the rest of column D is populated.